# Actionscript 3 - how to change existing MovieClips registration point

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, registration

Edit: If you're going to downvote, at least explain why -.-

I have a MovieClip in the Library. I right clicked the MC and clicked 'edit'.. According to tutorials I read, apparently now I am supposed to move a circle / crosshair? I cannot move the circle / crosshair (I see it, but I can't move it), the only thing I can move right now is the object itself, how do I change the registration point?

When I first created the MC, it showed my a grid and asked where I want the registration point, is there a way to get that grid again which maps the registration point?

Edit: According to this post:
[Change the position of the registration point in Flash CS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701403/change-the-position-of-the-registration-point-in-flash-cs5)

I'm supposed to just move the object in relation to the crosshair and that the crosshair signifies the registration point, which is incorrect. When I do that, in moves the entire movieclip and it doesn't change the registration point.

Note: I am using Flash CS5

Answer (score -1):

You can't "move" registration point, but you can move all inner clip content over it. Those silly crosshairs "pivots" work only in editor -- real registration point is always {0, 0} in clip local coordinate system.